# Google App Engine in Intellij CE / Android Studio?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-13

I've looked around and seen that Google App Engine is not available in IntelliJ CE, however, in Android Studio (built on IntelliJ) the plugin for GAE is available for install. Is it possible to build GAE apps on Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

yes, android studio allows you to create a backend for your app on app engine. see here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html